# How to release the NSUrlConnection class object,NSMutableData class object?

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection, nsurl

iam making one applciation.In that iam using the NSUrlconnection class.Below one is my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
responsedata = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.google.com"];
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSURLRequest *request=[[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:URL];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

[request release];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response 
{

   [responsedata setLength:0];
}
 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
[responsedata appendData:data];
   }

  - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    }
  - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

     [connection release];
    }
```

In this code when iam executing,it shows the memory leak at 
`responsedata = [[NSMutableData data] retain];`
`[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];` in `viewDidLoad()`
.SO please tell me where it released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should save reference to your `NSURLConnection` :

   `NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];`
2. You should start it:

   `[connection start];`
3. And you should release it in `didFailWithError` or `connectionDidFinishLoading`.

Comment: already connectionDidFinishLoading() have  connection object.In that method i released that one.